# how to use custom field of Owner in query?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a query like this:

```
lstTasks = [Select CreatedDate from Task where whatId in: accountIds AND Owner.custom_field__c=:BU order by CreatedDate desc];
```

I am unable to access the custom field from owner. Any ideas about to how to use this field in the above query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can not use the custom field of owner in Query. Also you can not use all the standard field  of owner in Query. Only limit fields which are global like  Owner.Id ,Owner.Username ,Owner.LastName ,Owner.FirstName ,Owner.Name, Owner.Title, Owner.Email etc can be used in Query.

If you required those field in query you can create Formula field like  Owner:User.custom_field__c .

Thanks